# CIRawFilter and camera-specific conversion parameters

Tags: macos, core-image, quartz-core, cifilter

For two years now, I have been getting back again and again at exploring Core Image's [CIRawFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIFilter/filterWithImageData:options:) capabilities to process RAW images on OSX / MacOS.

Initially, I got especially curious after watching [WWDC 2014 session 514](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/514/), in particular that impressive "RawExpose" sample as explained by dev Serhan Uslubas. I was hoping to really use these features, and control and improvements in Chromatic Aberration, Vignetting and optical distortions based on camera + lens data. In my experiments however with various (Canon) files, I didn't see any visible effect or error in the use of options like the one introduced in OS X v10.10:

> kCIInputEnableVendorLensCorrectionKey

Official documentation is sparse, and I did not find any sample code or in-depth user reports of its practical use. Searching leads me back to [my original question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/95617#95617) at Apple's developer forums.

With WWDC2016 ongoing, and the introduction of CIRawFilter to iOS and tvOS and "wide colors" and even shooting RAW on iDevices, I still did not spot any significant expansion on the documentation side, unfortunately.

Anyone have experience with obvious lens correction being correctly applied like shown in the WWDC 2014 Demo? Is there any reference and/or option to determine which (part of) features are compatible with which set of camera/lens types?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for iOS is now available!

[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/RawExpose/Introduction/Intro.html][1]